# What alternavies exists to OSXs "texturetool" for converting png image data to PowerVR

Tags: ios, iphone, compression, pvrtc

I'd like to know of alternatives to the command line program *texturetool* which comes with XCode for converting PNG Images to PowerVR compressed images.

For some reason *texturetool* takes about 50 seconds for converting some of the images I am working with. With about 1.3 mio images to be compressed, that would take several months.

Now I am looking for other tools running on either Linux or OSX, most preferable an in-memory C++ library, as the images are being generated procedurally.

Would love to get an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagination Technologies have just released an updated version of their [texture compression library](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtexlib.asp)  That may be worth trying.  (I know the page only says Windows and Linux but there appears to be a Mac version there as well).

Comment: Unfortunately one has to register, and the registration isn't working for me: I have yet to get any confirmation E-Mail.

Comment: @MHOOO - apparently you don't need to wait for the registration email - you should be able to log in (in fact you may already have been logged in) with your chosen username etc.

Comment: Yes, it actually works now. I've used the TexToolLib to do compression. Though it is a lot faster, is it possible to speed it up further by using multiple threads? i.e. is TexToolLib thread-safe?

Comment: The code was initially developed in Linux and can use pthreads (and equivalent in windows). I don't know what is used in the exported library. To be honest, the best place to ask is on the PowerVR Insider forum (http://imgtec.com/forum/) where I'm sure one of my colleagues would be happy to help.